# Python: Ignore case sensitivity for MYSQL column names

Tags: python, mysql

I am querying my MySQL DB with following code.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","test" )
cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
sql = "select * from student"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print row['firstname']
except:
    print "Error: unable to fecth data"
db.close()
```

Problem is that the column name specified in `row['firstName']` does not match and is case sensitive. Is there any way to ignore case sensitivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
sequence = cursor.column_names
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-column-names.html

Then compare your string to the actual name with .lower() and act accordingly